# insert new and insert close

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, commandfield

I'm having a problem,
so i have a form that contains an "insert and new" and an "insert and close" buttons .
the insert and new button lets you insert a row and reopens the form to insert another row . 
but the insert and close button closes after adding a row .
Anyways my problem is the following : 
I am using the command field in order to insert,update or delete from my database .

the insert and close button is working 
but the insert and new button is not because I'm not being able to add a row in my table . 
I just want to see if i can add an "Insert and new"button in my command field so i could use it (knowing that i already used all the buttons( delete,insert,update..)   .

Thanks .

Comment: show some code even if it's broken

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
    OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand">
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" EditMode="InPlace">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" UniqueName="ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="insert and new" CommandName="insertandnew" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="insert and close" CommandName="insertandclose" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
        new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1"},
        new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2"},
        new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3"},
         new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4"},
        new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5"}
    };

    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;

}

protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "insertandnew")
    {
        // Perform Your Insert operation
        e.Canceled = true;

        //Set insertmonde once again
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = true;
        RadGrid1.Rebind();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "insertandclose")
    {
        // Perform Your Insert operation
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = false;
        RadGrid1.Rebind();
    }

}
```